# angular 8 material required radio button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, metronic

I use metronic angular template for front in my application and i make radio button is required but I have problem is button radio is not required

code html :

```
<div class="form-group kt-form__group">
  <label class="example-margin">{{ 'PARTNER.TYPE' | translate }}</label>
  <mat-radio-group 
    name="typeNature" 
    required
    [formControl]="cartoonControl"
  >
    <mat-radio-button 
      *ngFor="let nature of partnerNatures"
       value="{{nature.id}}"
    >
      {{nature.label}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

code ts:

```
  initActivityEventForm() {
    this.PartnerForm = this.fb.group({

        firstname: ['', Validators.compose([ Validators.required,])],
        lastname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,])],
        organization: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,])],
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email])],
        phone1: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        phone2: ['', Validators.compose([])],
        typeNature: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        nature: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]

      }, {}
    );

  }
```

but field is not required, I add required to mat-radio-button but also error

Comment: Did you try to put the required attribute on the <mat-radio-button> ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a good pratice but try adding `[(ngModel)]` to your `mat-radio-group`.